# No 'Sass' Targets Found - Error whilst using Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-sass-lint

I've started trying to get to grips with the very basics of Grunt but when I try to run 'Grunt Sass' I get a "No 'sass' targets found" error. I can't see where I'm going wrong, anyone able to give me nudge in the right direction?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

//configuration
grunt.initConfig({
    // pass in options to plugins, references to files
    concat: {
        js: {
            src: ['js/*.js'],
            dest: 'build/script.js'
        },
        css: {
            src: ['css/*.css'],
            dest: 'build/styles.css'
        },
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    src: 'css/sass/styles.scss',
                    dest: 'css/styles.css'
                        }]
                   }
               },
    }

});

//Load Plugins
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');


// register tasks
grunt.registerTask('concat-js', ['concat:js']);
grunt.registerTask('concat-css', ['concat:css']);
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sass` task is nested in `concat` which is why it can’t identify the `sass` task and is returning a `No "sass" targets found.` error.

Un-nest your `sass` task like such:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    ...
  },
  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: [{
        src: 'css/sass/styles.scss',
        dest: 'css/styles.css'
      }]
    }
  },
});
```

Sidenote: Looks like your `css` task is misplaced as well, but that shouldn’t affect `grunt sass` or `grunt sass:dist` from running; however, it will not find `grunt sass:css`. If you want both `grunt sass:css` and `grunt sass:dist` to be available, remove the `css` task from `js` and here’s how you should struct your `sass` task:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    js: {
      src: ['js/*.js'],
      dest: 'build/script.js'
    },
  },
  sass: {
    css: {
      src: ['css/*.css'],
      dest: 'build/styles.css'
    },
    dist: {
      files: [{
        src: 'css/sass/styles.scss',
        dest: 'css/styles.css'
      }]
    }
  },
});
```